# Class not found PHP OOP

Tags: php, oop, autoloader

I can't get this to work.

```
<?php


        function __autoload($classname){
            include 'inc/classes/' . $classname . '.class.php';
        }



__autoload("queries")

$travel = new queries();
echo $travel->getPar("price");

?>
```

And this is the inc/classes/queries.class.php file.

```
<?

 class queries {

        function getPar($par, $table='travel', $type='select') {

            $result = $db->query("
             $type *
             FROM $table
             WHERE
             $par LIKE
            ");
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                return "
                 $row[$par]
                ";
            }

    }
}

?>
```

It returns "Class 'queries' not found". What's wrong with it?

EDIT:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare __autoload() (previously declared in /index.php:5) in /index.php on line 5

What the hell? I can't redeclare a function that is already declared in its own line, why?

Comment: Please don't pollute your question with nonsense content to get around the "too much code, not enough prose" restriction.

Comment: @Michael Well, what else to do? The restriction may be meaningful in general but in this case it prevented an a priori valid question from being asked.

Comment: I already edited it, I've no worries about that :)

Comment: @djpredator17: is your php configured with [`short_open_tag = on`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of that dreadful abomination, you should learn how to utilize [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php):

```
spl_autoload_register( function( $classname ){

    $filename = 'inc/classes/' . $classname . '.class.php';

    if ( !file_exists( $filename) ){
        throw new Exception("Could not load class '$classname'.". 
                            "File '$filename' was not found !");
    }

    require $filename;

});
```

And you should register the autoloader in your `index.php` or `bootstrap.php` file, and do it only once per loader (this ability lets you define multiple loaders, but that's used, when you have third party library, which has own autoloader ..  like in case of SwiftMailer).

P.S. please learn to use **prepared statements** with MySQLi or PDO.

**Update**

Since you are just now learning OOP, here are few things, which you might find useful:

Lectures:

- [Advanced OO Patterns](http://www.phpconference.co.uk/talk/advanced-oo-patterns)
- [Inheritance, Polymorphism, & Testing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc)
- [Recognizing smelly code](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wmgnFbsaPvo)
- [Global State and Singletons](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI)
- [Don't Look For Things!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0)

Books:

- [PHP Object-Oriented Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210117)
- [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420)

Comment: I just started with OOP, prepared statements will come a bit later, but really thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @djpredator17 , added few links that might help you

Comment: If I could vote up your post i would do it at least twice :) ty so much!

Comment: One line i forgot to add: [a tutorial for using PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). From what I have seem, most of PDO tutorials out there are quite dreadful and filled with mistakes/injectable code.

Answer (score 2):

Try so (without class autoload):

```
function __autoload($classname){
    include_once 'inc/classes/' . $classname . '.class.php';
}
$travel = new queries();
```

Also see this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: I did as you suggested but we are back to the "class queries not found" issue.

Comment: I suggest function __autoload, but you use function load and make so in function __autoload - var_dump($classname) - maybe troubles with paths.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class queries  in inc/classes/queries.class.php on line 4
That's the line where I declare it, for the first time (there's not a second time...)

Comment: Don't use call __autoload("queries")
and instead include use include_once

Comment: Even if I just include_once the file (correctly), it doesn't recognize the class.

Comment: Did you remove line __autoload("queries") ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13551/discussion-between-yantar-and-djpredator17)

Answer (score 0):

remove this line from you code `__autoload("queries")`, you don't need to call autoloader it will be called by it self whenever it encounters any undeclared class and use require_once instead of include and debug if you paths are correct or not.