# Why do I need to explicitly instantiate an object? 

Tags: php, oop

I am having a problem on my MVC framework. Here is my `loadModel()` method inside the main controller:

```
public function loadModel($name) {
$path = 'models/' . $name . '_Model.php';

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        require $path;  
        $modelName = $name . '_Model';
        $this->model = new $modelName;
    }
}
```

As you can see, when i try to load a controller, it automatically loads a model with the `same name + _model.php`.

I do not have any problem, when I use wamp or xampp, but, when I uploaded it in my website, it says `"Undefined property"` on every model. That means the model is not loaded. I know the problem is in there...

Is that some kind of an error in php.ini file of the server? Or maybe it because of different PHP versions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class not found PHP OOP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375225/class-not-found-php-oop)

Comment: Have you turned on full error reporting on your local server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows is not case sensitive, i.e. Model.php and model.php are the same as far as windows is concerned. ON unix/linux however (which I'm assuming your website server is) the file system IS case sensitive.

Basically, check your files names - if you're trying to load `$name_Model.php` but the file is `$name_model.php` it's going to fail when you upload it.

Comment: I think you are right!! i am loading it like for example
login_Model, whose class is Login_Model

now I Know!!! thank you, gotta test it now!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna consider using [autoloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php), that fixes all your problems:

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on relative paths, they depend on the current directory.

Make an absolute path like (adapt to your needs):

```
$path = __DIR__ . '/models/' . $name . '_Model.php';
```

If you get something like that to work locally, it should work on the server too.

BTW, i don't understand why _Model suffix. Wouldn't models/Car.php be sufficient ?